# order results by uniqueidentifer type column. is it reliable for my scenario?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has id column of type uniqueidentifier. This column is PK too. This column has a default value of NewSequentialID() however most of the time its been populated through NewID() function. This table has another datetime type column too. I need to order results from this table by datetime column but if value of datetime is same that I need to get the data in same order as it was inserted in this table ( meaning the row that got inserted first should display first). If I order my result by datetime first and then by Id column, will it give me what I need?

I know there could be better approaches ( like having some int type column with identity or something rather then relying on uniqueidentifier) but this thing is already in production and i need this sorting just for some repors.

Comment: See: [How are GUIDs compared in SQL Server 2005?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/11/06/how-are-guids-compared-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not reliable. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx):

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer **since Windows was started**. After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique.

It will probably work *most* of the time, but if your server has ever been restarted (and presumably it has if you are applying security updates) then you may run into problems. On the other hand, it's unlikely that there will be two rows inserted at the same time that the server was restarted so you may get away with it... but I'd *strongly* recommend changing your data model.

Answer (score 1):

No. GUIDs won't necessarily be assigned in insertion order. The problem is that if your table isn't recording the insertion order then you can't expect to reproduce that order.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp value is the surest way to order the rows in the sequence in which they were inserted.  You can test to see if more than one row has the same timestamp value:

```
            .... group by mytimestamp having count(*) > 1
```

I've never encountered that situation.

Comment: If he's not using the `GETDATE()` function and is manually inserting a value for the `DATETIME` it won't be reliable either.

Comment: Right.  Translate the question: I'm doing this the wrong way. Is there another way to do this that is reliable. Answer: no.

Comment: There are more then one rows for mytimestamp; this column has GetGate() as default value, however, there are more then one rows are inserted in a transaction that's why (I think) there are multiple values for same mytimestamp